# Make d3 observe a property in a dataset

Tags: d3.js

I'm trying to get around to fully understand how (and if) d3 observes changes to underlying data.

I've got this example working so far:

http://jsfiddle.net/AyKarsi/x95dk3uu/1/

Ideally I would  like to completely remove the necessity to call the

```
draw()
```

function and let d3 handle the changes to the data.

In a simple example, like the above it doesn't really matter what to update, but if there is a lot of data redrawing the whole graph doesn't feel right.. :)

So how can I improve the above example and make it more efficient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

d3 is not going to observe your `dataSet`. You still need to call `draw()`.

It feels right and it works fast because it reuses existing nodes every time you call `draw()`. Moreover you can use `key function` to bound elements to data, then even when order of the items change it will still reuse nodes with particular data.

Read more about `data` here https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#data and `key functions` here http://bost.ocks.org/mike/constancy/#key-functions

> Key functions can be useful for improving performance independent of
>   transitions. For example, if you filter a large table, you can use a
>   key function to reduce the number of DOM modifications: reorder DOM
>   elements in the update selection rather than regenerating them

Comment: So what is the purpose of D3’s update function if it doesn’t observe changes in the data?